# Regex Reject Consecutive Characters

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I am still very new to Regex and basically what I need to do is create a rule that accepts numbers and letters but no consecutive characters are allowed to be entered.

For example: abcd --> ok, abbcd --> bad

I have most of it to work but the part I cant figure out is exactly how do I prohibit consecutive characters?

My Code so far:

```
/^[A-Za-z-0-9]{8,15}$/i
```

Comment: At first I think minus sign between z and 0 is underline and if it's so you better use `[\w]` instead of `[A-Za-z_0-9]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> r = /^((\w)(?!\2))+$/i
>>> r.exec('abbcd')
null
>>> r.exec('abcd')
[ 'abcd',
  'd',
  'd',
  index: 0,
  input: 'abcd' ]
```

The `\2` part is a back reference and matches whichever character was last matched by the group `(\w)`. So the negative lookahead `(?!\2)` means "not followed by the character itself." If some terms I used here are unfamiliar to you, you should look them up on [MDN's Regular Expression Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

To limit the length of the accepted strings to 8-15 characters as in the OP, change the `+` to `{8,15}`:

```
>>> r = /^((\w)(?!\2)){8,15}$/i
>>> r.exec('abcd')
null
>>> r.exec('abcdabcd')
[ 'abcdabcd',
  'd',
  'd',
  index: 0,
  input: 'abcdabcd' ]
```

Comment: the thing with this answer is that it removed my limit rule which is that the user must input a minimum of 8 characters but no more than 16.

Comment: @shade917: You can change the `+` sign to `{8,15}` (from you question) to achieve that.