# Regex Reject Consecutive Characters including capital letter

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I reject three consecutive characters including a capital letter? For example: Bbblaska is not valid(Bbb).

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex Reject Consecutive Characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311424/regex-reject-consecutive-characters)

Comment: Not really a dupe of that, the case changing means that answer won't work here.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the capital letter part pretty easily by doing a case-insensitive RegEx match. Then it's just something like the following:

```
/([a-zA-Z])\1\1/i
```